# What does a negative value for the inclusive graphic standard deviation mean?

Tags: geology, rocks, sedimentology

I'm calculating the inclusive graphic standard deviation for sediment from a cumulative frequency graph, with this formula:

[image]

But when I plug in the numbers, I get a negative value, because my ranges at 5, 16, 84 and 95 span the 0φ boundary. What does this mean? Does this mean it is very well sorted, or have I made a calculation error?

My data:

[image]

Comment: This is the PDF with the formula: http://core.ecu.edu/geology/rigsbyc/rigsby/Sedimentology/CalculationOfGrainSizeStatistics.pdf (feel free to [edit] in to main question :))

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the question: According to pages 2 and 3 of the document, negative Phi values are not unexpected. The order of the Q values needs to be inverted: The 95% percentile needs to correspond to the lowest Phi value.

Comment: @daniel.neumann Ahh. I'm a bit silly... So my actual number should be 0.004545455?

Comment: How do you get 0.004545455? According to the plot on the right, one of the columns in the table on the right needs to be inverted - meaning that Q95 = 2.2, Q84 = 1.8, Q16 = 0 and Q5 = -1.2. Putting these values in the formula we get `(1.8+0)/4 + (2.2-(-1.2))/6.6 = 0.45 + 1.7/3.3 = 0.9652`. Thus, it is moderately sorted.

Comment: @daniel.neumann That -1.2 should be -0.8? But yes, I'd inverted them all, not just the 5 95. Thanks!